# Wix: How to limit major upgrades to major version numbers?

Tags: wix, limit, upgrade

I need the following behaviour from my wix-based installers:

- Every setup in the major version 1.x.x line should majorupdate any
  previous version of the 1.x.x line.
- Every setup in the major version
  2.x.x line should majorupdate any previous version of the 2.x.x line but
  leave the 1.x.x line alone.

I though I could get this to work with the following code, but the setup removed the previous 1.x.x version. Am I mssing something? Is this even possible?

```
    <Upgrade Id="myguid">
        <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="2.0.0.1" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" IncludeMinimum="no" />
        <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Maximum="2.0.0.1" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" IncludeMaximum="no" />
    </Upgrade>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a **NEW** GUID for 2.x if you don't want it to be "aware" of 1.x (i.e. ignore it, don't care, etc)

I use the following code, only changing `var.Property_UpgradeCode` when I want a new version to ignore previously installed versions (e.g. exist side-by-side in different folders)

```
<Product Id="*"
         UpgradeCode="$(var.Property_UpgradeCode)"
         Name="!(loc.ApplicationName)"
         Language="!(loc.Property_ProductLanguage)"
         Version="$(var.version)"
         Manufacturer="!(loc.ManufacturerName)" >

<MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"
          DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.LaunchCondition_LaterVersion)"
          MigrateFeatures="no"
          Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite tempted to use this solution as I can let MajorUpgrade handle everything for me. I'm just not sure if there are any serious drawbacks to this solution. Another thing: How's AllowSameVersionUpgrades been going for you? The documentation talks about the possibility of serious bugs ...

Comment: I wouldn't advise a public release without changing one of the first three digits. However AllowSameVersionUpgrades makes life a lot easier on the test/QA teams - we've encountered a few bugs, nothing that can't be fixed with a full remove/reinstall and a reboot however.

Answer (score 3):

Put @Minimum and @Maximum attributes on a single UpgradeVersion element to specify a range. Author multiple UpgradeVersion elements to specify multiple version ranges.

Comment: Thank you! Should have been quite obvious. I'm tempted to use MajorUpgrade with a changed UpgradeCode though (as saschabeaumont answer suggests). Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: No drawbacks based on your requirements.